# CSS overflow breaks item's initial width

Tags: css, sass

Considering the following code structure.

Is it possible to make the background of the item to stretch with the item and not be limited to the initial width of the `.scroll` container?

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="item active">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem, ipsum dolor. ipsum dolor</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.list {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
}

.scroll {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 2.5rem;
    padding: 0 16px;

    &.active {
      background: red;
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is a code [example](https://codepen.io/desig9stein/pen/bGVjWJB)

Comment: Consider not SHOUTING

Comment: @CertainPerformance, is there any problem?

Comment: try inline-flex instead of flex and min-width:100% instead of width:100%

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you, works perfectly, exactly what i needed. Much appreciated! You can put this as an answer to the question so I can mark it as answered

Comment: Ther is one more way of fixing it, if we don't care about IE, we can use width: fit-content